# 502 Bad Gateway Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: nginx, elixir, phoenix-framework, ubuntu-18.04

I've set up a new Ubuntu 18.04 server and deployed my phoenix app but am getting a 502 error when trying to access it.

I don't yet have a domain name because I will be transferring one from another server, so just trying to connect with the IP address.

The Phoenix app is deployed and running, and I can ping it with edeliver.

Prod conf:

```
config :app, AppWeb.Endpoint,
  load_from_system_env: false,
  url: [host: "127.0.0.1", port: 4013],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json",
  check_origin: true,
  root: ".",
  version: Mix.Project.config[:version]

config :logger, level: :info

config :phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true

import_config "prod.secret.exs"
```

Nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4013;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

Nginx Error log:

```
2020/05/14 22:28:23 [error] 22908#22908: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ipaddress, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4013/", host: "ipaddress"
```

Edit:

Last two entries of OTP logs confirming app is alive

```
===== ALIVE Fri May 15 07:33:19 UTC 2020

===== ALIVE Fri May 15 07:48:19 UTC 2020
```

Edit 2:

I have posted a Gist detailing all the steps I have taken going from a clean Ubuntu box to where I am now here: https://gist.github.com/phollyer/cb3428e6c23b11fadc5105cea1379a7c
Thanks

Comment: `4013` port looks suspicious. Can you share your `config/prod.exs` (assuming you build and deploy the release for `prod` environment.)

Comment: I've edited the question to add `config/prod.exs`. Yes, I'm building and deploying to `prod` environment.

Comment: check your server logs, most probably it doesn't start for some reason

Comment: That was the first thing I did, the app is alive, and I can ping it with `edeliver`. I'll add the last couple of entries to the question.

Comment: can you please add to your question the content of `releases.exs` file?

Comment: I don't have a `releases.exs` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved as follows:

There were two problems that required resolving.

1. Adding `config :app, AppWeb.Endpoint, server: true` to either `prod.secret.exs` or `prod.exs` was required.
2. I had a running process left over from mistakenly deploying `staging` to the same server, initially. I originally logged in to the server, and stopped staging with `./bin/app stop`, maybe this left a process running, maybe somehow I started the process by mistake later on. Anyway, I used `ps ux` to list the running processes and found that one of the processes listed `staging` in its path, so I killed **all** running processes related to the deloyment, both staging and production, with `kill -9 processId`, re-deployed to production, and all is now fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `server: true` to your configuration, like:

```
config :wtmitu, WtmituWeb.Endpoint,
  server: true,  # <-- this line
  load_from_system_env: false,
  ...
```

You don't have to add it to the `dev` environment because `mix phx.server` is doing it for you.

The [Doc](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-runtime-configuration)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment so I wrote an answer instead. I hope this is the right reason. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but this was already in `prod.secret.exs`, but it is part of the solution